# How to disable the airplane mode in android version 4.3 rooted device?

Tags: android

I have been working to turn off airplane mode(if airplane mode is in ON state) in rooted device version 4.3. The below following code doesn't work in android version 4.3. It's works fine up to the version 4.2.

```
Settings.Global.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                        "airplane_mode_on", 0);
                isAirplaneModeOn = isAirplaneModeOn(context);
                Intent localIntent2 = new Intent(
                        "android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE");
                localIntent2.putExtra("state", isAirplaneModeOn);
                context.sendBroadcast(localIntent2);
```

Please let me know if anybody have any idea/code to turn off airplane mode in rooted device version 4.3?